# request for data to test deterministic ecdsa signature algorithm for secp256k1

Tags: elliptic-curves, dsa, deterministic-encryption

I’m implementing the RFC 6979 procedure to compute a message signature. I want to test my program on the secp256k1 elliptic curve. Note the “k” in secp256k1, i.e. the Koblitz curve.

If you have the reliable implementation of RFC 6979 on your machine, I would like you to post data that I could use to test my code.

The data should look like this:

1. The private key in hexadecimal form that you use.
2. The message in plain text or in hexadecimal form that you use before it’s hashed. I will use SHA256 to obtain the hash of the message.
3. The value of “k” in hexadecimal form that your software produces.
4. The value of “r” in hexadecimal form that your software produces.
5. The value of “s” in hexadecimal form that your software produces.
6. Optionally, the complete signature in hexadecimal form that your software produces.

Comment: Thread on bitcointalk that has several test vectors: [Deterministic Usage of DSA and ECDSA Digital Signature Algorithms (RFC 6979)](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=285142.msg3150733)

Answer (score 2):

Here are 20 test vectors for SECP256k1 (RFC6979): ([Source](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=285142.0)).

The format is (private key, message, DER signature).

Its not in the format you needed but the final signature should validate all the other values.

```
(1,Absence makes the heart grow fonder.,3045022100AFFF580595971B8C1700E77069D73602AEF4C2A760DBD697881423DFFF845DE80220579ADB6A1AC03ACDE461B5821A049EBD39A8A8EBF2506B841B15C27342D2E342)
(2,Actions speak louder than words.,304502210085F28BBC90975B1907A51CBFE7BF0DC1AC74ADE49318EE97498DBBDE3894A31C0220241D24DA8D263E7AF7FF49BCA6A7A850F0E087FAF6FEF44F85851B0283C3F026)
(3,All for one and one for all.,30440220502C6AC38E1C68CE68F044F5AB680F2880A6C1CD34E70F2B4F945C6FD30ABD03022018EF5C6C3392B9D67AD5109C85476A0E159425D7F6ACE2CEBEAA65F02F210BBB)
(4,All's fair in love and war.,30440220452D4AB234891CF6E5432CD5472BDCA1CFC6FB28563333885F068DA02EE216D8022056C368D16A64D29CFF92F17203D926E113064527AF0480D3BCC1D3FADFDE9364)
(5,All work and no play makes Jack a dull boy.,3045022100995025B4880EEB1ECEDBA945FE8C9B2DDF2B07DBC293C2586C079D7B663EF38A022022FB54AB95014616D014277E05C97A7ED9E22596A0420BBD2D749CA9A2F876FE)
(6,All's well that ends well.,3045022100A9C1593FA6459777B2EBA6D7E2A206E3BB119E85B2163973CF28FFAF24EC381C02202F166F13230B3853B928EFB649D30375EC6A4B1A64A8D56FBCC0A9D86A0943E9)
(7,An apple a day keeps the doctor away.,304402202FC9C8B749621241C33FD51B57FC5140C1D7FC1594F91B073953E79DA2F5E8F60220345E4EA7693B5069C0251771EA476CBE236586ED24B90AEEEA7B7C2814EDF477)
(8,An apple never falls far from the tree.,3044022052B6E2C49A6F6ADBE52FB6BBE744CAA3F49364085DB118EAB8670BC766BE160302207D96A42866637CA3D4CAF36E597A460EB305ADAC0220B027410C821A7191A1C4)
(9,An ounce of prevention is worth a pound of cure.,3045022100BE53E7C00788E4417083D7511800F18C7C6F5F259DE39BC6F8B1BEBCD5056BD002201F389E13CFE7D1DBD8D2D1BFF18138219F57DE166673762009686A28FBC44DF6)
(10,Appearances can be deceiving.,304402202F2413A1673F642C30EA2E23FCAE45776BC77A94F96920AEA3C14303B1469428022053AC3E8EA0A488E9159D56E429A51F207BF04E462F8D4BA2C69B1B1635F30217)
(34356466678672179216206944866734405838331831190171667647615530531663699592602,Absence makes the heart grow fonder.,3045022100996D79FBA54B24E9394FC5FAB6BF94D173F3752645075DE6E32574FE08625F770220345E638B373DCB0CE0C09E5799695EF64FFC5E01DD8367B9A205CE25F28870F6)
(99398763056634537812744552006896172984671876672520535998211840060697129507206,Actions speak louder than words.,304502210088164430985A4437471417C2386FAA536E1FE8EC91BD0F1F642BC22A776891530220090DC83D6E3B54A1A54DC2E79C693144179A512D9C9E686A6C25E7641A2101A8)
(3759719655879806965811134282268177329967523491661175987246621825209053686213,All for one and one for all.,30450221009F1073C9C09B664498D4B216983330B01C29A0FB55DD61AA145B4EBD0579905502204592FB6626F672D4F3AD4BB2D0A1ED6C2A161CC35C6BB77E6F0FD3B63FEAB36F)
(103660229287485550546857170818258546832194359524010586713457827121778385264241,All's fair in love and war.,304502210080EABF24117B492635043886E7229B9705B970CBB6828C4E03A39DAE7AC34BDA022070E8A32CA1DF82ADD53FACBD58B4F2D3984D0A17B6B13C44460238D9FF74E41F)
(104702657257102633579772822622124422673143939576486771274630765314225900831707,All work and no play makes Jack a dull boy.,3045022100A43FF5EDEA7EA0B9716D4359574E990A6859CDAEB9D7D6B4964AFD40BE11BD35022067F9D82E22FC447A122997335525F117F37B141C3EFA9F8C6D77B586753F962F)
(46744469262201639974910661553202053327388301297897803474665777634455660653814,All's well that ends well.,3044022053CE16251F4FAE7EB87E2AB040A6F334E08687FB445566256CD217ECE389E0440220576506A168CBC9EE0DD485D6C418961E7A0861B0F05D22A93401812978D0B215)
(91461772442478604154082755547318472082410323943823420797096392355159818037369,An apple a day keeps the doctor away.,3045022100DF8744CC06A304B041E88149ACFD84A68D8F4A2A4047056644E1EC8357E11EBE02204BA2D5499A26D072C797A86C7851533F287CEB8B818CAE2C5D4483C37C62750C)
(86354370597268376573642079301756246922349732255591245149271869674095200273050,An apple never falls far from the tree.,3045022100878372D211ED0DBDE1273AE3DD85AEC577C08A06A55960F2E274F97CC9F2F38F02203F992CAA66F472A64F6CCDD8076C0A12202C674155A6A61B8CD23C1DED08AAB7)
(19584093032798730129230525910686445865718710074652466673872143043325364812985,An ounce of prevention is worth a pound of cure.,3045022100D5CB4E148C0A29CE37F1542BE416E8EF575DA522666B19B541960D726C99662B022045C951C1CA938C90DAD6C3EEDE7C5DF67FCF0D14F90FAF201E8D215F215C5C18)
(781437121688497986836158713061237152541328908182646473971063062031575438443,Appearances can be deceiving.,304402203E2F0118062306E2239C873828A7275DD35545A143797E224148C5BBBD59DD08022073A8C9E17BE75C66362913B5E05D81FD619B434EDDA766FAE6C352E86987809D)
```